# What's the best way to append json object to a file without duplication?

Tags: python, file, duplicates, append

```
def append_json_to_file(self, file_path, json_obj):
    with open(file_path, 'a+') as f:
        f.seek(0)
        duplicated = 0
        for line in f:
            if json.loads(line) == json_obj:
                duplicated = 1
                break
        if duplicated == 0:
            json.dump(json_obj, f)
            f.write('\n')
```

I'd like to append a JSON object to a file. If the object already exists in the file, I'm going to skip this object.

This is what I have done. I'm wondering is there a better way to implement the function.

Comment: How big is the file? Could you read the whole lot into memory at once? If so, you could read the whole lot as a single string and test whether `json.dumps(json_obj)` is in the file. This would save the time you currently take in parsing each line.

Comment: That's a great idea. The file has only thousands of lines. But I don't quite understand how to compare a string with a json object. Are you going to convert the json object to a string as well?

Comment: Yes, that’s what json.dumps() does.

Comment: I’d calculate the hash - https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html  - of json.dumps(json_obj).  Then read each line and calculate its hash.  If the hashes match you’ve already written it.  If you get to the end and no match, append the already calculated json.dumps.

Comment: If you were really shooting for speed you could even maintain a “cache of hashes in file” as a set.